# How to rename a file with sftp get command

Tags: linux, command, rename, sftp

Is there a way to use a "get" command in sftp to get a folder without obtaining "Cannot download non-regular file:..../dir_name" or to get a file and save it with another name?

In the second option I mean:

```
sftp> ls
hello.txt
sftp> get hello.txt (+ something) byebye.txt
sftp> exit
```

And in my directory I have `byebye.txt`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

no need any params, just

```
sftp> get hello.txt byebye.txt
```

Comment: and if I need a multiple get like get all files with that last date modified and all the got file should  end with that date?     ... how can I do something like this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: This simply does not work for me.  sftp just downloads the original file without changing the name. Tectia Client 6.3.11